# Что такое Development support,

Tags: терминология, mobile-development

Что означает **Development support**?
Этот термин включает в себя фронтенд и бекенд веб сайтов и мобильных приложений или что-то другое?
Помогите пожалуйста понять смысл термина.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это не имеет прямого отношения к веб разработке. Development support - это такая услуга, которая часто продается вместе с продуктом (или ее можно купить отдельно), который используется для разработки.

К примеру, используете mongo и возникли проблемы. Обычно программисты идут на сайты и форумы, такие как этот и пытаются решить. А можно купить у них [специальный сервис](https://www.mongodb.com/products/development-support) и Вам будут помогать специальные люди, часто это программисты, которые непосредственно работают над продуктом. Возможно, даже соберут спецсборку для Вас или напишут немножко кода.

Подобное предоставляют и другие компании - [RedHat](https://access.redhat.com/support/offerings/developer), IBM, Oracle. Мне известны случаи, когда сотрудники Оракла выезжали в датацентр к заказчику и поднимали упавшую базу по среди ночи.

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение!

Comment: А после отезда сотрудиков Оракла из датаентра, штатные сотрудники этого самого датацентра без премий остались, как минимум на месяц.

Comment: сотрудники датацентра не обязаны подымать Вам базу. Их задача в другом.  А бекапы - они то могут и испортиться, быть неверно настроенными и тому подобное. А часто их и нельзя просто так применить.